# how to replace a function variable with a value from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through the below dictionary and replace the "string" variable inside the function with the values from the dictionary and then execute the function. I am thinking about writing a for loop and then include the function inside the for loop. Please help.

expected function:

> ```
> def my_function(fname):
>     string = value  
>     print(string + " Refsnes")
>
> my_function("string")
> ```

```
 dict = {"kafka":[{
"value":"I am"},
{"value":"You are"},
{"value":"They are"}
]}

def my_function(fname):
    string = "I am"  
    print(string + " Refsnes")

my_function("string")
```

Comment: The function does nothing with the value passed as an argument. It's not clear what you want from this.

Comment: I am basically trying to replace the "string" variable inside the function with the values from dictionary and run the function. I want to loop through the dictionary values and run the function. @roganjosh

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.  Did you get the dictionary from elsewhere, or are you setting it up yourself?  And is there a specific reason you need to define a function?  If you're setting it up yourself, I would advise you to use a list instead of a dictionary, and to just do a for loop all by itself, like this:

```
kafka = ['I am ', 'You are ', 'They are']
for k in kafka:
    print(k + 'Refsnes')
```

If you need it to be a dictionary and you need it to be a function, I would approach it like this. (Note that you don't need a function to pull an item out of a dictionary, so I would actually put the loop inside the function.)

```
kafkadict = {"first person": "I am", "second person": "You are", "third person plural": "They are"}
def printKafkaStuff(dictinput):
    for k in dictinput.values():
        print(k + " Refsnes")
```

Then call it with

```
printKafkaStuff(kafkadict)
```

Comment: Still works for me - maybe a difference across different versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to first modify your dict. Right now "kafka" maps to a list of dicts that all have the same key, so why bother and have a key in the first place.
So you could have a dict like:

```
dictionary = {"kafka": ["I am", "You are", "They are"]}
```

Also do not call the variable `dict`, because you would overwrite the built-in function `dict`, which makes it unusable.

Then you also have to change your function to actually make use of the paramter.

```
def my_function(string):
    print(string + " Refsnes")
```

And now, to loop over the dict an print the function with all the values you have two options.

First loop over the list in the dictionary and call the function repeatedly:

```
for string in dictionary["kafka"]:
    my_function(string)
```

Or give a list to your function and loop over the list in the function. Your function would then look like this:

```
def my_function(list_of_strings):
    for string in list_of_strings:
        print(string + " Refsnes")

# Call function with 
my_function(dictionary["kafka"])
```